# Number of TCP connections after close() and exit() calls

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

```
pid_t pid;
int listenfd, connfd;
listenfd = socket(...);
bind(listenfd, ...);
listen(listenfd, 5);
connfd = accept(listenfd, ...);
if ((pid = fork()) == 0){
    close(listenfd);
    doit(connfd); /* processes the clients request*/
    close(connfd);
    exit(0);
}
wait(...)
```

How many TCP connections will I have after the call of the wait function?
I think it should be 0, but I don't really know what the close() function does. Does it close every process or only one process (either the child or the parent process)?
Thank you!

Comment: As far as I understand after fork all the file opened file descriptors without `O_CLOEXEC` flag will be duplicated and present in both parent and child process and each process will need to close his descriptors separately. That is after fork you end up with 4 descriptors - `listenfd` and `connfd` in each process. Each process needs to close both of them.

Comment: Yes but 4 file descriptors aren't equivalent to 4 TCP connections, right?

Comment: So at `wait` line TCP connection is still held by server. Because it haven't closed connection socket yet.

Comment: Is there any call to `shutdown()` involved on any copy of `connfd` inside the code you do *not* show?

Comment: I suppose not. This is from an exam and all you have is this code and the question. Nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*One* successful call to `accept()` sets up exactly *one* connection. For a *blocking* listening socket it returns the **connected** socket<sup>*1</sup>.

After forking, the server refers to this *one* connection using its copy of  the connected socket `connfd`.

Then the process forks and the second process holds a copy of `connfd`.

Both those two socket descriptors refer to the *same* connection.

(The **listening** socket never really refers to a connection. It's just sort of a sensor, listing for incoming requests.)

<sup>*1</sup>For an *unblocking* listening socket things are a bit different in terms of timing. In such a case it might be that connection setup is not completely done the moment `accept()` returns.

---

So to answer your question:

> How many TCP connections will I have after the call of the wait function?

After the call to `wait()` only one copy of the two socket descriptors referring to the connection `accept()` established had been `close()`d. The other still "holds" the connection.

Assuming the code does not call `shutdown()` anywhere or makes any socket unblocking adjusting your code a bit the pattern typically looks like this:

```
listenfd = socket(...);
bind(listenfd, ...);
listen(listenfd, 5);

connfd = accept(listenfd, ...);

/* Connection is up. */

if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
{
  /* Connected child process here */

  close(listenfd); /* Close the connected processes's listening listenfd 
                      as it never uses it. */
  doit(connfd); /* Processes the clients request. */

  close(connfd);

  exit(0);
}

/* Listening parent process here */

close(connfd) /* Close the accepting process' connected connfd 
                 as it never uses it. */
wait(...)

/* Definitely no connection here any more */
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! It makes sense now, as I didn't quite understand what was closed when the close() function was called.